# Android dev - Issue with using SeekBar

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm trying to implement a SeekBar in a simple flashlight app (that I'm learning on) and cannot understand why the app keeps crashing when I set the OnSeekBarChangeListener to my SeekBar.  As soon as a remove all of the code inside the onStopTrackingTouch() for the listener, the app runs fine.  But if there is anything at all inside the listener's methods, it crashes.  I'm also using buttons and gestures in the app and have not had any problems using those.

I am bringing up a separate layout when the user presses the Menu button | Brightness option, which displays the SeekBar (to adjust the brightness)

Here is the how I am implementing the SeekBar:

```
SeekBar mSeekBar;

...

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.main);

...

mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.mSeekbar);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //first set the brightness mode to manual
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

                //change the actual setting
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                float brightness = Float.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()); //change the brightness here
                lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
                getWindow().setAttributes(lp); //set the new brightness
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Thank you for your time and advice.

UPDATE:  Here is the link to my Logcat info  http://pastie.org/2561098

UPDATE 2: Here is the link to my release run LogCat info:  http://pastie.org/2561111

SOLVED:

I had mSeekBar being instantiated and the listener's set before the layout was present.  The SeekBar was null because the separate layout I made for adjusting the brightness was not currently in view.  Putting the instantiation and listener's inside the switch statement I use for options menu, after the new layout (for the brightness) is set works perfectly.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error? If it crashes it must give the exception.

Comment: If I try to use debug mode on the emulator or on my device, eclipse throws this diabolical error saying the "source not found" and it then gives me an option to edit the path to the source (even though it is pointed to the correct place).  In the emulator, no msg is given, just that the app was force closed.  I'm using Galileo on my win 7 64 bit pc.

Comment: I get the source not found errors because I don't link to the full Android source either. You must either hit f6 to continue stepping, or f8 to run to your next breakpoint. Also - open your LogCat view, this displays everything that is happening in the Android system - including the error that caused the force close. Window > ShowView > Other > Search for LogCat

Comment: Can you please print the logcat related to it?

Comment: LogCat is up above in the link (debug first and then release run).  @Jack, I get the source not found errors even if I try to step through the app..

Comment: Set a break point at the very beginning (in onCreate()). Then use f6 to "step over". If you step IN, you are probably stepping into the "source that eclipse cannot find". If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your answer. On line 77 of your onCreate method your program is crashing because of a NullPointerException. The answer is in the stack trace, while these look perplexing, they actually point you to the exact line of code that caused the crash (most of the time).

```
at com.polaniec.myflashlight.MyFlashLightActivity.onCreate(MyFlashLightActivity.java:77)
```

When you dig through the stack trace you want to look for the part that indicates YOUR actual class name and method name (not all of the android.os... or java.lang... methods). The 77 means it is line 77 in your code. Whatever you are referencing is null, maybe it was not instantiated?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Line 77 is the line where I set the mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener up.  Specifically, this line up above:  mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

Comment: Are you sure mSeekBar is not null? Maybe it has a different name in the XML? Remember it is case sensitive (so mSeekbar is not the same as mSeekBar). Also since you can remove the code in onStopTrackingTouch and it works fine, this could mean that it is something in that method. Continue stepping line by line until that method is hit. Then step into and through that method (line by line - f6) and it should crash on the problem line.